# Receiving "502 Bad Gateway" fron Cloudfront when scraping a website?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-cloudfront

I've built a scraping script in PHP to gather information from a particular website. I have tested the script thoroughly with downloaded HTML files from the target website, so the xpath queries are correct. Yesterday I tried the script for the first time locally but targetting the actual website and it worked. So I then took the script, placed it on my server farm, and turned it on.

This morning I awoke to 90 emails from one particular server telling me there's been an error. Another server sent about 10 emails, while the other two seem to be working away just fine. I've checked the logs I keep on the database and all of the errors encountered have been "502 Bad Gateway". I've tried the URL through a normal web browser and it loads fine, and I've tried the URL via a wget method on the same server. The wget returns this error:

> ERROR: The certificate of `http://www.targetwebsite.com` is not
>   trusted.
>
> ERROR: The certificate of `http://www.targetwebsite.com` hasn't got a
>   known issuer.

​Using the "--no-check-certificate" flag still produces the error, but downloads the HTML file anyway.

So anyway, in my script I have the following code:

```
// Assign Curl Options
$curlOptions = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => 'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1',
CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookiesJar,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
);

// URL To scrape
$url = "https://www.targetsite.com/specific/page/";


// Build Curl Headers
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

​
So this tends to work, but obviously isn't 100% reliable at the moment due to Cloudfront returning 502 Bad Gateway errors. But, at the same time, I've never created a web scraping script before, and while I'm sure that's all the options I need to make the website think I'm a legitimate user, well obviously I'm missing something!

From some reading I've done, there was talk about how you would need to pass on ciphers through to the target site. So I added this to the curl options:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA ,AES128-GCM-SHA256, AES256-GCM-SHA384, AES128-SHA256, AES256-SHA, AES128-SHA, RC4-MD5',
```

I've noticed some improvement, but I'm still getting a fair number of 502's.

If anyone could help me that would be amazing.

Comment: What rate are you scraping at? ISTR Cloudfront offer anti-scraping measures to their clients.

Comment: I generate a random interval between 30 seconds to 15 minutes (obviously in seconds), which goes above the code and sleeps the script for that amount of time. This goes for any links it finds as well.

Comment: Seems reasonable. It might be something beyond your control, like a misconfigured server behind a load balancer. But I have no specific ideas so will butt out.

Comment: No thats fine @markdwhite thanks for your input

Comment: *while I'm sure that's all the options I need to make the website think I'm a legitimate user, well obviously I'm missing something!*  You're apparently missing the fact that if you are having to pretend to be a legitimate user, then it is inappropriate to ask for help in this forum.  Get permission from the site to do what you are doing, or stop doing it.

Comment: It's not for anything illegal, it's a means to test what I'm doing for a paper I am writing. The most obvious issue when scraping a site is that it looks just like that, a bot scraping a site. I'm not trying to do that at all. And even so, not having permission doesn't explain why you would get a 502 error randomly for a small portion of requests.

Comment: Well, I have a similar situation.  I'm using pushshift's API wrapper around reddit, and as far as I can tell they give no indication of rate limits or any other TOS limits.  I'm not scraping.  I'm calling the documented public API and parsing the JSON response.

If I had some idea of what the limit was, I would follow it.  I do know that you can get banned, but it happened to one IP and not another, so still doesn't help.  Am I supposed to guess what the limits are? Your advice to get permission is completely useless.  As far as I can tell, there's not anybody to ask permission of.